# Applescript exclude file types on zip

Tags: macos, automation, zip, applescript, finder

I need to adapt an applescript I have to exclude several file types. I think I need something like -x "*.fla*" but I can't seem to get the syntax working.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if input is {} then -- no dropped items
        tell application "Finder" to set input to selection as alias list
    end if
    repeat with x in input
        set _path to POSIX path of x
        tell application "Finder"
            if kind of x is "Folder" then tell me to zipFolder(_path)
        end tell
    end repeat
end run

on zipFolder(theFolderPath)

do shell script "tDir=" & (quoted form of theFolderPath) & "; cd \"$tDir\"; aZip=\"../$(basename \"$tDir\").zip\"; if [ -e \"$aZip\" ]; then rm \"$aZip\"; fi;  zip -r \"$aZip\" ./"
end zipFolder
```

Thank you for any help you can give

Answer (score 0):

Add the exclude option before the last double quote:
`./ -x *.fla"`